# android onactivityresult data.getData() returns null in a fragment

Tags: android

I am trying to upload and image captured with camera.
I am calling the camera from a fragment and I am using tabs.

Here is how I call the camera:

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
```

Here is how I am trying to capture the image:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    // boolean processed = true;

            if(requestCode==CAMERA_CAPTURE){

              thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
              img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

            }
```

}

I can display the image after I take the photo, but when I am trying to get the URI of the picture, I an getting null on :
    Uri uri = data.getData();

Every help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

try like that

```
if(data != null)
    {           
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        String filestring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

      Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filestring);
         img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

    }
```